# Infinite summation of the series $ \frac {n}{ (n-1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Infinite summation of the series $$ \frac {n}{ (n-1)!}$$

I tried expanding and even tried to split this up, applied ratio test just to see if it converging.

**The Answer given to me is $2e$**

I think the given question is wrong or at least the answer is wrong, could anyone please confirm if i'm right or wrong. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What's the least $n$ in your sum? If it's $k$, please write the series with a question edit as e.g. $\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$ (`\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}`). You can solve the problem using $\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{m!}=e$ and, for $n\ge2$, $\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$.

Comment: The given  answer is correct. Just write the numerator as $(n-1)+1$. If you got a different answer you should show your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach to that mentioned in the comment.
You have
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}  = e^{x}
.\end{align*}
Now you can differentiate and exploit properties of power series to differentiate termwise to obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = e^{x}
.\end{align*}
Now multiply by $x$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n}}{n!} = e^{x}x
.\end{align*}
Differentiating again and multipying by $x$ yields
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2}x^{n}}{n!} = x (e^{x} + x e^{x}) 
.\end{align*}
Now you can plugin in $x = 1$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2}}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{( n-1)!} = ( e^{} + e^{}) = 2e
.\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You can direktly calculate the sum:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n{(n-1)!}
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac {n+1}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {n}{n!} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac 1{n!}}_{\textstyle =e} \\
&= \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {1}{(n-1)!}}_{\textstyle =e} + e
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the function

$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}$

The power series converges for all real $x$.

Show that $f(x)=xe^x.$

and $f'(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$